# Which part of the Bootstrap CSS affect the navbar li elements, when you click on a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering, because when I click on a dropdown menu the thickness of the li navbar elements decreases. Using the standard layout:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="imgs/logo.png"></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
**<li><a href="services.html"><span class="navli">SERVICES</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="navli">OUR WORK</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="navli">ABOUT</span></a></li>**
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="imgs/english.png" style="padding-right:3px;margin-left:-5px;"><span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/deutsch.png">  Deutsch</a></li>
<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/espanol.png">  Español</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Does anybody know where the CSS is for this.

And another question:

Is there a way of seeing the CSS changes being applied, when an action occurs? Maybe I can try to find out that way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you inspect the element (i.e., using Google Chrome) and right click on the DOM element, it will give you an option to select the state `:active, :hover, :focus, etc`. The developer tools will also provide you the style and what line it is in the style sheet. Here's an overview of Chrome DevTools - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0):

That would be the following snippet if you are using the 'default navbar'
(Line 4498 in [bootstrap.css](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/))

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of seeing the CSS changes being applied, when an action occurs? Maybe I can try to find out that way.

I suggest learning how to use your browser's developer tools. DevTools are great for examining, editing and debugging. Below are links to the How tos for IE, Firefox and Chrome. You can also Google search for your specific browser to learn how to use their devtool (If it's available).

- Internet Explorer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx
- Google Chrome - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics
- Mozilla Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I tried finding it with the developer tools.
Changing the color unfortunately doesn't do the trick. It is more and issue of the width, that changes when the dropdown is active and the other li > a elements react.